# Is my NVIDIA driver working or not?

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, wayland, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

If run the command

```
 prime-select query
```

it returns

```
 nvidia
```

However, if I run nvidia-smi, it looks like my nvidia processor is not being used.

[image: screenshot of nvidia-smi output]

I can't use nvidia-settings to diagnose because for some reason it won't open on my computer. If this is a Wayland issue, well gnome crashes immediately with Xorg when I have 410 nvidia driver installed.

Update: If I run

```
 dmesg | grep nvidia
```

I get the following output: [link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OkeR.png)

Update 2: If I run

```
 inxi -G
```

I get the following output: [link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLSYI.png)

Comment: Any output for `dmesg | grep nvidia`?

Comment: Nvidia-settings can't be used in a wayland session. Also if this is an Optimus laptop then Nvidia drivers are not supported in wayland. (in 18.04 when logging into wayland you'll automatically be switched to Intel if Nvidia drivers are in use on Optimus machines

Comment: What does `inxi  -G` report?

Comment: I am also using 410 in xorg. "dmesg" message have no special meaning. It means a property driver is loaded. And my nvidia driver working. Might be the issue said by doug. Try to run "sudo journalctl -r -p err ".

Comment: Your inxi shows that you are using Intel. If you want to use Nvidia then it can only be via xserver. So you'll need to resolve that.